# If I have a world on Terraria with one character can you access the world with another character?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

If I have one world and one character can I go on the world with a different character?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That is one of the great things about Terraria. Any character can go on any world.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did this once when I lost my character, so I created a new character and went to my world and took stuff from chests.